# Getting the record that contains different node value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this order xml which always contain 2 billing information, I need to get that 2nd billing info that contains different parent_id to shipping information.

```
<parent_id xsi:type="xsd:string">49835</parent_id>

<ns1:salesOrderInfoResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento">
    <result xsi:type="ns1:salesOrderEntity" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <increment_id xsi:type="xsd:string">100002388</increment_id>
        <store_id xsi:type="xsd:string">3</store_id>        
        <order_id xsi:type="xsd:string">37260</order_id>
        <shipping_address xsi:type="ns1:salesOrderAddressEntity">
            <parent_id xsi:type="xsd:string">37260</parent_id>
            <address_type xsi:type="xsd:string">shipping</address_type>
            <firstname xsi:type="xsd:string">Test</firstname>
            <lastname xsi:type="xsd:string">Test</lastname>
            <company xsi:type="xsd:string">Test King</company>
            <street xsi:type="xsd:string">73 Punggol Central</street>
            <city xsi:type="xsd:string">Singapore</city>
            <region xsi:type="xsd:string">Singapore</region>
            <postcode xsi:type="xsd:string">828756</postcode>
            <country_id xsi:type="xsd:string">SG</country_id>
            <telephone xsi:type="xsd:string">03 8888 22244</telephone>
            <region_id xsi:type="xsd:string">491</region_id>
            <address_id xsi:type="xsd:string">74520</address_id>
        </shipping_address>
        <billing_address xsi:type="ns1:salesOrderAddressEntity">
            <parent_id xsi:type="xsd:string">37260</parent_id>
            <address_type xsi:type="xsd:string">shipping</address_type>
            <firstname xsi:type="xsd:string">Test</firstname>
            <lastname xsi:type="xsd:string">Test</lastname>
            <company xsi:type="xsd:string">Test King</company>
            <street xsi:type="xsd:string">73 Punggol Central</street>
            <city xsi:type="xsd:string">Singapore</city>
            <region xsi:type="xsd:string">Singapore</region>
            <postcode xsi:type="xsd:string">828756</postcode>
            <country_id xsi:type="xsd:string">SG</country_id>
            <telephone xsi:type="xsd:string">03 8888 22244</telephone>
            <region_id xsi:type="xsd:string">491</region_id>
            <address_id xsi:type="xsd:string">74520</address_id>
        </billing_address>      
        <billing_address xsi:type="ns1:salesOrderAddressEntity">
            <parent_id xsi:type="xsd:string">49835</parent_id>
            <address_type xsi:type="xsd:string">shipping</address_type>
            <firstname xsi:type="xsd:string">Test</firstname>
            <lastname xsi:type="xsd:string">Test</lastname>
            <company xsi:type="xsd:string">Test King</company>
            <street xsi:type="xsd:string">73 Punggol Central</street>
            <city xsi:type="xsd:string">Singapore</city>
            <region xsi:type="xsd:string">Singapore</region>
            <postcode xsi:type="xsd:string">828756</postcode>
            <country_id xsi:type="xsd:string">SG</country_id>
            <telephone xsi:type="xsd:string">03 8888 22244</telephone>
            <region_id xsi:type="xsd:string">491</region_id>
            <address_id xsi:type="xsd:string">74520</address_id>
        </billing_address>      
    </result>
</ns1:salesOrderInfoResponse>
```

What I've tried so far is this.

```
//*[local-name()='billing_address'][*[local-name()='billing_address']/*[local-name()='parent_id'] != *[local-name()='shipping_address']/*[local-name()='parent_id']]
```

But it says no matching record

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is: `<parent_id xsi:type="xsd:string">49835</parent_id>` in the second `<billing_address>` tag? If so, this xpath should find it for you:

```
//billing_address[2]/parent_id
```

Comment: sometimes billing_address is on first index.

Comment: Okay so I just need to clarify a bit. You need to get the `billing_address` that has the `parent_id` that is different to the one contained in `shipping_address`. But this `billing_address` can change between index 1 or 2?

Comment: I see. I'm not quite sure how to do this in one xpath. Can you not first use a xpath to get the `parent_id` for `shipping_address` and then use that to look for the `billing_address` that has the different `parent_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `xpath`.

```
//billing_address/parent_id[text()!=//shipping_address/parent_id]
```

To get the entire node.

```
//parent_id[text()!=//shipping_address/parent_id]/parent::billing_address
```

Comment: its only giving me the parent_id, i need the entire billing_address. anyways, i'll give this an upvote